# Restore common variables between inherited types

Tags: c#, reflection

I have two classes: `GameObject` and `SampleObject : GameObject` and a list of type `GameObject`. I've serialized instances of these classes into a XML document. My problem occurs once I deserialize (load) this document.

In XML file instances are serialized as:

```
<Root>
 <GameObject>
  <Type>Namespace.MyType</Type>
 </GameObject>
</Root>
```

Where **Type** represents desired type. And each instance is serialized under **GameObject** tag.

After parsing this document I obtain a list of `GameObject`. Now I need to restore correct type:

```
foreach (GameObject g in myList)
{
  GameObject tempObject = (GameObject)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(g.TypeString));              
}
```

Problem is that `tempObject` is blank (which is correct). I'd like to (with some shorthand) restore common (shared) variables between `g` and `tempObject`. Ex:

```
tempObject.Property1 = g.Property1
tempObject.Property2 = g.Property2
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to deserialize `SampleObject`-specific properties as well?

Comment: I would. @C.Evenhuis

Comment: In that case I wouldn't deserialize as `GameObject` first at all - what type of serializer do you use? `XmlSerializer` for instance has some built-in support for this.

Comment: I'm using XmlSerializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` supports polymorphism, but you'll have to indicate up front which types to exprect. You can do this using an attribute on the base type:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(SampleObject))]
public class GameObject
{
}
```

You can also pass these types to the constructor of `XmlSerializer`, for instance if you don't own the `GameObject` class. Full example:

```
Root root = new Root();
root.Objects.Add(new GameObject { Property1 = 2 });
root.Objects.Add(new SampleObject { Property1 = 5, Property2 = 12 });

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root), new Type[] { typeof(SampleObject) });
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    ser.Serialize(stream, root);
    stream.Position = 0;
    Root deserialized = (Root)ser.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

It outputs the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <GameObject>
    <Property1>2</Property1>
  </GameObject>
  <GameObject xsi:type="SampleObject">
    <Property1>5</Property1>
    <Property2>12</Property2>
  </GameObject>
</Root>
```

I used the below classes for this example:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Root
{
    public Root()
    {
        Objects = new List<GameObject>();
    }

    [XmlElement("GameObject")]
    public List<GameObject> Objects { get; set; }
}

public class GameObject
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class SampleObject : GameObject
{
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This actually connected gaps in my knowledge. I already had output in format of <GameObject xsi:type="SampleObject"> but had no idea how to use this xsi:type. Just for clarification, could you extend your answer with how'd the situation change if there was one more type, ex. SampleObject2?

Comment: And one more question. Imagine that there are plenty of these types inheriting from GameObject. Is there any way to automate extension of [XmlInclude(typeof(SampleObject))] or do I have to add every type by hand?

Comment: You could use reflection on startup to collect all types inheriting from `GameObject` and store them in a `Type[]` - which you can then supply to the `XmlSerializer` constructor.